# Cannot upgrade Material-Ui Version from 0.14.4 to 0.15

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to upgrade Material UI from 0.14.4 to 0.15.0.

I have a custom theme and I'm following the changelog to avoid any error.

However, i'm facing a problem in the process.

Here are some screenshots of the problem. Does someone know where it comes from and how to fix it?

[image]

Here is the code where the 'Uncaught TypeError' come from :

[image]

thanks in advance for anyone having an insight/solution to my problem

Edit :
Here is my code

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

let MainApp = React.createClass({/*...*/});

ReactDOM.render((
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <MainApp />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your code

```
static contextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Add it where you need to access the muiTheme.

**Since we both have updated our questions and answers the comments are not valid any more**

Comment: This is an equivalent of what I've done. So, always the same error :(

Comment: @Jean-YvesDELMOTTE Can you complement your first post with the app wrapper and how the Dialog component looks?

Comment: this.context.muiTheme is undefined. Are you sure that you wrapped the Dialog?

Comment: I updated my post with the app wrapper. Concerning the Dialog component, it is a basic one as you can find in the docs, it was working under 0.14.4

Comment: Do I have to do something particular to wrap the Dialogs in the 0.15.0 ? I didn't see anything in the documentation.

Comment: What React version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112372/discussion-between-edgesoft-and-jean-yves-delmotte).

Comment: React : 15.0.1 Mui : 0.15.0

Comment: Okay, I just found out the solution. I was mounting manually React Components in gmap infowindows somewhere in my code. I forgot that they was out of React scope so ... Sorry for taking some of your time, it helps me a lot to identify the problem ! Big thanks !